# Dúvida em um jquery com div print

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

seguinte dúvida, tenho um código javascript que ele faz impressão de uma div pelo id, só que o seguinte, é um formulário, gostaria de personalizar, com cabeçalho  e imagens, é possível sem que eu tenha q inserir os dados na div?

La vai o script:

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    //IMPRESSÃO - A O CONTEUDO QUE SERÁ IMPRESSO DEVERA ESTAR DENTRO DE UMA //DIV CHAMADA print
    $("#imprimir").click(function () {        
    $("#botoes").hide();       
    $("#print").show();
    window.print();         
    $("#botoes").show();       
});
EXPORTAR PARA PDF - O CONTEUDO DA EXPORTAÇÃO DEVERÁ ESTAR DENTRO DE UMA DIV CHAMADA PRINT
$("#pdf").click(function () {
      var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','letter');
        var specialElementHandlers = {
            '#print': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    pdf.addHTML($('#print').first(), function() {
        pdf.save("RelatorioPdf.pdf");
    });
});   
EXPORTAR EXCEL - O CONTEUDO DA EXPORTAÇÃO DEVERÁ ESTAR DENTRO DE UMA DIV CHAMADA PRINT
$("#excel").click(function () {
    var htmltable= document.getElementById('print');
    var html = htmltable.outerHTML;
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(html));
});

});
```

Há e outra dúvida aproveitando, como eu aplico UTF-8 nessa exportação?
Dúvida besta eu sei, porém sou apenas um novo padawan nessa área de desenvolvimento.
Valeu  e obrigado a puder ajudar.